# Seeking free database solution for Delphi starter editon and / or Lazarus

Tags: gratis, database, delphi, lazarus-ide

Tl;dr Looking for a gratis database solution for Borland Delphi and/or Lazarus, preferably compatible with both.

---

As Delphi has become increasingly ridiculously overpriced, I have begun to seek (an) alternative(s).

If you don’t make income of more than US $1,000 with it, then you can use the free [Delphi starter edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter-faq).

If you plan to earn more, or just plain don’t like commercial software, even when it is free, then the open source [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) is compatible to Delphi to a great extent and provides a (one way) [conversion tool](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Delphi_Converter_in_Lazarus)  .

You can Google for comparisons between these two great IDEs if you want to, but if you have read this far then you probably know one of them and would find the other very similar, so you only need to Google for specifics.

As I said, I am dissatisfied with the price or commercial Delphi editions, and am seeking to achieve the same functionality with either the free Delphi starter edition, or with Lazarus.

The differences between the various Delphi editions is shown in a [27 page PDF document](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-berlin-feature-matrix.pdf).

As far as I can see, the ***major*** differences (are others important to you?) are that the free Starter edition:

- Has no database connectivity
- Has no internet connectivity
- Only produces 32 bit executables

I can live with the third of those, but am seeking a free solution which includes the first two. This can be either for Delphi starter or for Lazarus, preferably for both.

For a database solution, I have so far found [ZoesLib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/). Does anyone use an alternative solution, which they would recommend? Preferably something well documented and supported.

For internet acess, please see [sister question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39497/seeking-free-internet-access-solution-for-delphi-starter-editon-and-or-lazarus).

Comment: Lazarus supports connecting to Postgres as far as I can tell: http://wiki.freepascal.org/postgres and ZoesLIB seems to work with Firebird if you want an embedded database: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq337/

Comment: Sounds good, anonymous equine quadruped. Alas, I am only conversant with MySql and Sqlite, but this will certainly help others.

Comment: According to the Lazarus Wiki, it also supports MySQL: http://wiki.freepascal.org/mysql

Comment: Great!  You can post that as an answer, if you want to

Comment: Zeos in combination with mysql is a good fit :)

Comment: Thanks. That would be http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/ ?